# How to calculate the midheaven?

Tags: python, math

I am trying to get a medium Coeli degree, using the [Wikipedia calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midheaven#Use_in_astrology), but I can't get the exact degree. Please help me, how to calculate it?

Code was

```
def medium_coeli_degree(degree):

    # Medium Coeli general formula
    # mc = arctan(tan θ / cos ε )
    # where as the θ is the degree of the planet, ε is the obliquity which is 23.43672

    radians = math.radians(degree)
    tan_theta = math.tan(radians)

    # cos ε (which is constant, the formula is provided here and general cos ε value is 0.917499911138)
    # sidereal_degree = 23.4367
    # sidereal_radian = math.radians(sidereal_degree)
    # cos_e = math.cos(sidereal_radian)
    cos_e = 0.917499911138

    # Dividing the Tan theta and Cos epsilon
    tan_by_cos = tan_theta / cos_e

    # Change the Tan by cos value into radians
    tan_by_cos_radian = math.radians(tan_by_cos)
    mc = math.atan(tan_by_cos_radian)

    return mc
```

The final degree should be 0 to 360 but not able to get the degree within that.

Comment: `math.atan()` returns radians, as per the documentation. You'll want to convert to degrees, if that's what you want.

Comment: You are talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midheaven#Use_in_astrology ?

Comment: yes, exactly.  I am talking about that one.

Comment: The input to `math.atan` is *not* an angle: it's a ratio. Thus, you should *not* convert the input for `math.atan` to radians (or degrees, for that matter), but use it as-is: `mc = math.atan(tan_by_cos)`, then convert the resykt to degrees (if you so want), since `mc` will be in radians: `return math.degrees(mc)`.

Comment: Side note: cos ε is not constant, it's only constant for a specific point in time (as also mentioned on the relevant Wikipedia page). It hardly matters, but just to be precise.